# How can I compute element-wise conditionals on batches in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I basically have a batch of neuron activations of a layer in a tensor `A` of shape `[batch_size, layer_size]`. Let `B = tf.square(A)`. Now I want to compute the following conditional on each element in each vector in this batch: `if abs(e) < 1: e ← 0 else e ← B(e)` where `e` is the element in `B` that is at the same position as `e`. Can I somehow vectorize the entire operation with a single `tf.cond` operation?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may want to look at [`tf.where(condition, x, y)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where)

For your issue:

```py
A = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, layer_size])
B = tf.square(A)

condition = tf.less(tf.abs(A), 1.)

res = tf.where(condition, tf.zeros_like(B), B)
```

Comment: In Tensorflow 1.0, it's now `tf.where` 

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/comparison_operators#where

Comment: what if we need to pass function into `tf.where`